# How to transfer the logical expression to list of list?

Tags: list-manipulation, logic

As described in the title, I would wondering:

How to transfer the solutions give by the following code

```
neweqns=Sin[a] + Sin[a - b] == 0 && 
 Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 
  0 && ((Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b] == 0) || 2 Sin[b] == Sqrt[3] || 
   Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[b] == 0)

result = 
  Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi], {a, b}, 
    Reals] // FullSimplify;

(*(b == 0 || b == \[Pi] ) && (a == 0 || a == \[Pi])) || (3 a == 2 \[Pi] && 
       3 b == 4 \[Pi]) || (3 a == 4 \[Pi] && 3 b == 2 \[Pi])*)
```

to the following list of list?

[image]

Thanks a lot for any suggestion!

Comment: You're probably missing an initial `(` in the code.  Does `{a,0,b}/.Solve[conds,{a,b}]` accomplish your task, where `conds` is the logical expression?  Of course, the symmetry of `a` and `b` isn't elided by `Solve`.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! I think it would not work, since the solutions given by ```Solve``` does not align with the format ```{a=..&&b=..}||{a=..&&b=..}||{a=..&&b=..}```.

Comment: @Adam Here is the code: ```result = {a, b} /. 
   Reduce[neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi], {a, b}, 
    Reals] // FullSimplify```, and it gives error ```"{(a==0&&(b==0||b==\[Pi]||b==2\ \
\[Pi]))||(a==(2\\[Pi])/3&&b==(4\\[Pi])/3)||(a==\[Pi]&&(b==0||b==\[Pi]||\
b==2\ \[Pi]))||(a==(4\\[Pi])/3&&b==(2\\[Pi])/3)||(a==2\ \
\[Pi]&&(b==0||b==\[Pi]||b==2\ \[Pi]))} is neither a list of \
replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used \
for replacing."```

Comment: In general `/.`, [Replace](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Replace.html), is used with [Solve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) and not with [Reduce](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html).  Do you specifically want a flat `Or` of {a=..&&b=..} possibilities instead of {a=..b=..||..}?  You should write the question to reflect that instead of the list that is there.

Comment: Starting with your expression, `{a, 0, b} /. {Reduce[expr] // ToRules}` However, there are six results not three.

Comment: @Adam Thanks! I just edited the question to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LogicalExpand` "threads" all solutions.

```
neweqns = 
  Sin[a] + Sin[a - b] == 0 && 
   Sin[a] + Sin[b] == 
    0 && ((Sin[a] == 0 && Sin[b] == 0) || 2 Sin[b] == Sqrt[3] || 
     Sqrt[3] + 2 Sin[b] == 0);

result = Reduce[
    neweqns && 0 <= a <= 2 \[Pi] && 0 <= b <= 2 \[Pi], {a, b}, 
    Reals] // FullSimplify;

{a, 0, b} /. Solve@LogicalExpand[result] // Sort

(*   {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, Pi}, {0, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  {(2*Pi)/3, 0, (4*Pi)/3}, {Pi, 0, 0}, 
  {Pi, 0, Pi}, {Pi, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  {(4*Pi)/3, 0, (2*Pi)/3}, 
  {2*Pi, 0, 0}, {2*Pi, 0, Pi}, 
  {2*Pi, 0, 2*Pi}}   *)
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable "result" from your computation  looks like:

```
((b == 0 || b == \[Pi] || b == 2 \[Pi]) && (a == 0 || a == \[Pi] ||a == 2 \[Pi])) || 

3 b == 4 \[Pi]) ||

 (3 a == 4 \[Pi] && 3 b == 2 \[Pi])
```

We have 3 different cases and the first case has different possibilities.

Now you want something like {a,0,b}. Although I do not understand the 0 in the middle we can get this from:

In the first case we get replacement rules directly from "ToRules":

```
{a, 0, b} /. {ToRules@result[[1]]}
```

[image]

In the second and third case we must first solve for a and b:

```
{a, 0, b} /. Solve[result[[2]], {a, b}]
```

[image]

```
{a, 0, b} /. Solve[result[[3]], {a, b}]
```

[image]

All in all we have 11 solutions.